# The difference between wildcards in match & like in Azure Policy

Tags: azure, policy

I'm coding Azure policy using the JSON structure documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure

Would somebody be able to confirm if it's possible to use the asterisk wildcard and the "?", "#", or "." on the same statements.  As it says, I think you can only use asterisk on like comparisons and the others on match comparisons.

etc.
Many thanks

My tag field must start with 4 numbers, then a semi-colon but after that I don't care what is coded.  Ideally this would be

```
####;*
```

But I'm finding I have to code
    ####;.
or
    ####;..
or
    ####;...
etc.

```
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "in": "[parameters('type')]"
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "anyOf": [
            {

              "field": "[concat('tags[','tag_name', ']')]",
              "match": "####;"
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[','tag_name', ']')]",
              "match": "####;."
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[','tag_name', ']')]",
              "match": "####;.."
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[','tag_name', ']')]",
              "match": "####;..."
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[','tag_name', ']')]",
              "match": "####;...."
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[','tag_name', ']')]",
              "match": "####;....."
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[','tag_name', ']')]",
              "match": "####;......"
            },
```

etc.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: please try just use ####;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot use the asterisk wildcard (*) in a `match` clause.

However, you can use a [*value* clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#value)  with the [take and field function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-functions)s to achieve your desired result:

```
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "in": "[parameters('type')]"
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "value": "[take(field('tags[tag_name]'), 5)]",
          "match": "####;"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "audit"
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after, thanks very much.